# ajax conflict when trying to integrate paypal

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I'm trying to integrate paypal payment, but I have a problem since I'm using ajax to send the shopping cart data to the create order. It show me this alert: **Failed to load https://linktothepaypallogin Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access.**

Create order php:

```
<?php

session_start();

 if(isset($_SESSION['pay']) && $_SESSION['pay']=="Paypal"){
unset($_SESSION['pay']);
    header("location:PayPal-PHP-SDK/paypal/rest-api-sdk-php/sample/payments/AuthorizePaymentUsingPayPal.php");
    exit();
}

?>
```

JS:

```
function validate_order(){
$.ajax({
 url: "create_order.php",
});
}
```

I'm sure the problem is ajax, because if I try with submit it works as intended.

Comment: looks like you're trying to access "linktothepaypallogin" in an XMLHttpRequest on the browser, and due to the type of request, the browser performs a CORS preflight, which is failing ... none of the code you've shown would result in that error

Comment: yes that's the problem I don't know how can I make the browser properly redirect me to the paypal link instead of showing me that error.

Comment: don't use XHR for cross origin requests that are not allowed by the other domain - the code in the question has *nothing to do with your error* - so, it's hard to actually help *at all*

Comment: well I was thinking it was something with ajax, cause if i use a input submit to the same create.php it works as if should.

Comment: The Ajax you show in the question is same origin, so is not going to result in a cross origin error. Oh wait. I see now. You're redirecting the request to a different host. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

create_order.php should be

```
    <?php 
    session_start();

     if(isset($_SESSION['pay']) && $_SESSION['pay']=="Paypal"){
        unset($_SESSION['pay']);
        echo "PayPal-PHP-SDK/paypal/rest-api-sdk-php/sample/payments/AuthorizePaymentUsingPayPal.php";           
      }

    ?>
```

And JS page should be

```
function validate_order(){
 $.POST("create_order.php",false,function(e){
    window.location.href = e;
 });
}
```

Comment: sorry if this is one stupid question but should I replace the  $.POST  with $.ajax? in any case if I copy  and paste the JS code exactly like you wrote it it show me an error of: $.POST is not a function but if I replace it witch $.ajax its deprecated.           I'm really sorry but i'm a noob in JS,

Comment: both can be use.it's your choice  . $.post( "create_order.php", function( url) {
  window.location.href = url;
});